# Left Join a Single Random Record MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a single row at random from the `Sponsor` table joined to the `Company` table. The follow query **almost** works but will sometimes return a `NULL` Sponsor.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
SELECT C.ID AS CompID, C.Name AS CompName, S.ID AS SponID, S.Name AS SponName 
FROM Company C 
     LEFT JOIN Sponsor S ON S.ID = (SELECT ID FROM Sponsor WHERE Company = C.ID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

Data Sample:

```
Company Table
| ID | Name      |
|  1 | MyCompany |

Sponsor Table
| ID | Company | Name    |
|  1 |     1   | Bruce   |
|  2 |     1   | John    |
```

Query Results in one of the following:

```
| CompID | CompName  | SponsID | SponName |
|    1   | MyCompany |    1    |  Bruce   |

| CompID | CompName  | SponsID | SponName |
|    1   | MyCompany |    2    |  John    |

| CompID | CompName  | SponsID | SponName |
|    1   | MyCompany |  NULL   |  NULL    |
```

Comment: If anyone can even tell me why this is happening that would be great.

Comment: Show sample data. If a company has no sponsor there is nothing you can do.

Comment: In this case company has 2 Sponsors. The Query will return either Sponsor1, Sponsor2 or NULL.

Comment: Then create sample data witc can reproduce that behaviour. Better create a deomo on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler - I don't see anything wrong in your query.

Comment: Just created the test data above in sqlfiddle.com, and got the exact results that I am showing. I'm baffled, are you?

Comment: do you want to select for one company or multiple company?, mean do you use company id to filter result, in that case you can modify the query a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `RAND()` your subquery is not deterministic and thus is executed for every row in `Sponsor` table and every time retuns a random ID which might match or not the ID of the current row. So it's not only possible, that no row will match the random ID. It's also possible that multiple rows will.

For the sample data with two sponsors the subquery may return folowing values:

- (1, 1) will match the first row (1=1, 2=1)
- (1, 2) will match both rows (1=1, 2=2)
- (2, 1) will match no row (1=2, 2=1)
- (2, 2) will match the second row (1=2, 2=2)

To guarantee that the subquery is executed only once, you can use it the SELECT clause. Then join the result as derived table with the `Sponsor` table:

```
SELECT C.*, S.Name AS SponName 
FROM (
    SELECT C.ID AS CompID, C.Name AS CompName, (
        SELECT ID FROM Sponsor WHERE Company = C.ID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
    ) as SponID
    FROM Company C
) C
LEFT JOIN Sponsor S ON S.ID = C.SponID
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/LSSJT25902

Comment: I am not understanding. Doesn't the WHERE clause filter out only the rows I need, and the LIMIT 1 just get the first record?

Comment: Your WHERE filter is not static but dynamic and random on every call.

Comment: That is friggin Awesome! Thanks!