# More than one result on Primary Key search

Tags: mysql, database

I've been having issues with my MySQL query. I'm currently trying to make a procedure that will randomly populate a bridging table with magic tricks for a particular booking.

After fighting the procedure for hours I've narrowed the issue down to this line of code.

```
SELECT *
FROM avaliable_tricks WHERE table_id = FLOOR(RAND() * 144)+1;
```

I'm trying to retrieve the information of a trick using a randomly generated number that will equal its primary key. It **should** only grab one entry, as its using a primary key, and primary keys are unique values. In reality its grabbing 0, 1, 2 or more entries with no rhyme or reason. IE. it just returned 4 rows, with primary keys of 2, 5, 47, and 107.

I can't think of any reason why it isn't working, other than the fact that its a randomly generated number.

Is there something inherently wrong in my code?

EDIT:
Here is a DESCRIBE ran on my temporary table.

```
table_id    int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
show_trick_id   int(11) YES         
trick_length    int(11) YES         
recommended_age int(11) YES
```

Comment: You may get better answers if you include a "Describe" of your table as shown here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: are you sure is `table_id` is pk for `available_tricks`?  The pk should be call`id` or `available_tricks_id`

Comment: Its a temporary table that I'm testing on. Its definitely the primary key, as I made the table within the last hour.

Comment: This statement is out of scope. Please create a simple but full and  reproducible example.

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183331/left-join-a-single-random-record-mysql/42191623#42191623 - rand() will generate a new value for **every row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAND() is executed once for every row in your table and generates different values. If you want to get only one random number you can use a subquery (derived table);

```
SELECT *
FROM avaliable_tricks 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 144)+1 as rnd) r
WHERE table_id = r.rnd;
```

Or just use a variable

```
SET @rnd = SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 144)+1;
SELECT *
FROM avaliable_tricks 
WHERE table_id = @rnd;
```